# getElementByID returns null (jsfiddle inside)

Tags: javascript, html, null, getelementbyid

I'm trying to create custom buttons for a media player. The tricky part is that I want the play button to become a "loading" button that will later become a pause button but anyways.

I'm using 4 `div`s - `stop` / `play` / `loading` / `pause`, the last two being hidden (display:none;). I want to display the loading div instead of the play div when you click on the latter (in addition to activating the player). Yet when I call `lyricsPlay("B")`,`document.getElementById("lyrics" + el + "1")` seems to be returning null.

The stop button closes the container `div` (a popup which will contain the player), and stops the player. This part works fine.

Being pretty much a newbie when it comes to javascript, I'm sure this is a stupid mistake on my part but I'm at a complete loss in finding where it is. I've read many posts about `getElementById()` returning null but none of the solutions seems to apply to my case.

Below is my HTML code, but you can fiddle with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kX83R/1/):

```js
function lyricsToggle(div_id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
  if (el.style.display == 'none') {
    el.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function lyricsStop(videoID, divID) {
  lyricsToggle(divID);
  //jQuery('#lyrics' + videoID).tubeplayer('stop');
}

function lyricsPlay(el) {
  var play = document.getElementById("lyrics" + el + "1"); //returns null??
  var load = document.getElementById("lyrics" + el + "2"); //returns null??
  lyricsToggle(play);
  lyricsToggle(load);
  //jQuery(video).tubeplayer("play");
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.lyricsPlay {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
}

.lyricsStop {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}

.lyricsLoad {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

.lyricsPause {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  display: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">

    <div id="lyricsB0" class="lyricsStop" onClick="lyricsStop('B', 'container')">
      stop
    </div>

    <div id="lyricsB1" class="lyricsPlay" onClick="lyricsPlay('B')">
      play
    </div>

    <div id="lyricsB2" class="lyricsLoad" onClick="lyricsLoad('B')">
      loading
    </div>

    <div id="lyricsB3" class="lyricsPause" onClick="lyricsPause('B')">
      pause
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please use proper indenting when posting code, e.g. using http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a element as `div_id` already to `lyricsToggle()` with:

```
var play = document.getElementById("lyrics" + el + "1");// as div_id
lyricsToggle(play);
```

so **no need** to do this inside `lyricsToggle(div_id)`:

```
var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
```

Try this:

```
function lyricsToggle(div_id) {
    var el = div_id; // and not: var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN7uD/)